# Res vs Obiectus

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, meaning, word-comparison

What is the difference in meaning between Res and Obiectus (is it merely a matter of Language evolution Classical vs Medieval)?

As a meaning I am interested in that which (the thing that) is related to something else (this other thing would be denoted-declined in a genitive) mainly as its Topic its Purpose or its Reason (Something's (the other thing's) Objective or the Subject of Something).

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples? I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: @brianpck https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethica_practica Ethica practica est investigatio philosophica, ex cosmotheoria morali, certarum rerum provinciae privatae et publicae quae sunt res iudicii moralis.

Comment: Latin has two words *obiectus*, namely the participle of *obicere* and the noun *obiectus, -us*. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I was talking about obiectus the noun.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that res is more abstract, as in affairs, etc.. while objectus is (as the name suggests) more objective, i.e. a physical object rather than an abstract concept.

Comment: So then how did Subject acquire this meaning of Res? In Latin we would say Res iudicii. In English we would say The Subject of judgement. How and why did the semantics shift?

Comment: @Drwhops Could you perhaps give a few examples how *obiectus* is used in this way, or perhaps point to a dictionary?

Comment: Downvoted. I cannot square this answer with what my dictionaries tell me about the meaning of (either) *obiectus*.